# SFTP connection from Eclipse to Google Cloud Instance

Tags: eclipse, ssh, google-cloud-platform

I am struggling to connect my Eclipse Remote environment to my Google cloud Instance.
I have generated a public and private key with ssh-keygen on my mac and stored them in the ~/.ssh folder. I copied the public key to the google cloud using the metadata and added the key to the ssh keys listed. I also added the private key to eclipse in the SSH2 settings. Trying to connect give me error:  Failed to connect sshd on " my ip-address".
The strange thing is that Filezilla can connect in this way, but `i would like the comfort from Eclipse. Can somebody help me with this problem??

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to access by sftp with Filezilla that means that your ssh-keys are correct, I recommend you put the ssh-key in the metadata section of the instance, here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide) with the steps.

To connect with eclipse:

Try the [Remote System Explorer](http://tmober.blogspot.com/2006/11/remote-system-explorer-10-is-released.html) (RSE). It's a set of plug-ins to do exactly what you are looking for.

RSE may already be included in your current Eclipse installation. To check in Eclipse Indigo go to Window > Open Perspective > Other... and choose Remote System Explorer from the Open Perspective dialog to open the RSE perspective.

To create an SSH remote project from the RSE perspective in Eclipse:

1. Define a new connection and choose SSH Only from the Select Remote
   System Type screen in the New Connection dialog.
2. Enter the connection information then choose Finish.
3. Connect to the new host. (Assumes SSH keys are already set up.)
4. Once connected, drill down into the host's Sftp Files, choose a
   folder and select Create Remote Project from the item's context
   menu. (Wait as the remote project is created.)

If done correctly, there should now be a new remote project accessible from the Project Explorer and other perspectives within eclipse. With the SSH connection set-up correctly passwords can be made an optional part of the normal SSH authentication process. A remote project with Eclipse via SSH is now created.

Comment: Both setting up the keys in the General metadata section and setting up the public key in the VM instance did not work either, still unable to connect via the Remote System Exporer Eclipse.

Comment: I found this video that could help you, try it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aj0MuB8RJ6I